# unable Copy sources from target to destination for Package

Tags: java, file-io

I am trying to implement a function that can get from my source directories to file preparation package directory to migrate into servers. This a function using the target and destination to copy the all the java file to respective files that if i stated on the package folder.

```
private static void copyfilesforsurce(File source, File dest) throws IOException { 
    FileChannel sourceChannel = null;
    FileChannel destChannel = null;
    try {
        sourceChannel = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
        destChannel = new FileOutputStream(dest).getChannel();
        destChannel.transferFrom(sourceChannel, 0, sourceChannel.size());
       }finally{
```

> sourceChannel.close();

```
           destChannel.close();
   }}
```

but i getting bellow exception AS:

```
at preparepackage.preparepackagefolder.copyFileUsingJava7Files(preparepackagefolder.java:82)
    at preparepackage.preparepackagefolder.access$14(preparepackagefolder.java:74)
    at preparepackage.preparepackagefolder$3.actionPerformed(preparepackagefolder.java:233)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

> the exception line is highlight as  sourceChannel.close();

Comment: And what is the exception?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: System.out.println(File source ::  File dest)
sourceD:\bv_data\onlinebanking_enquiry
destD:\Trash\ChangeFolder\bv_data\onlinebanking_enquiry

Answer (score 1):

You have a NullPointerException at the line `sourceChannel.close();`.

That means that the line `sourceChannel = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();` did not complete successfully.

The line `sourceChannel = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();` does not complete successfully if `new FileInputStream(source)` throws a `FileNotFoundException`, of which the [FileInputStream JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream-java.io.File-) says:

> FileNotFoundException - if the file does not exist, is a directory rather than a regular file, or for some other reason cannot be opened for reading.

To validate this you could add the following lines at the beginning of your method:

```
System.out.format("%s - isFile: %b, isDirectory: %b, canRead: %b", 
    source, source.isFile(), source.isDirectory(), source.canRead());
```

This line should output the name of your source file, followed by " - isFile: true, isDirectory: false, canRead: true".

---

To copy all files from a directory into some other directory you can use [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/), the  [FileUtils.copyFile](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyDirectory-java.io.File-java.io.File-) method:

```
FileUtils.copy(source, dest);
```

Comment: isFile: false, isDirectory: true, canRead: trueException in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @ Thomas Klanger, Actually I am trying to copy files from one folder to another folder but the caution currently is that i felt it a command to read files and copy to another file. do you have any Solution that i can utilize to copy files from one folder to another. 

Something like Folder A(Contain 5 Java Files) and Folder A_Backup which copies that 5 java file on one Click.

Comment: @kuhandransamudrapandiyan i've updated my answer with how to copy directories